# how to do Like button implementation?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, mern

I'm using localstorage for storing user id and then sending it to state, then using it to hide like button after clicking it, but after clicking like button, it doesn't disappearing and user can keep liking the post(many times).

Login code: Here I store the user in localstorage and dispatch it.

```
               localStorage.setItem("user",JSON.stringify(data.user))
               dispatch({type:"USER",payload:data.user})
               history.push('/c')
```

userReducer code:

```
export const initialState = null

export const reducer = (state,action)=>{
    if(action.type==="USER"){
        return action.payload
    }
   return state
}
```

Like functionality:

```
const likePost = (id)=>{
            fetch('/post/like',{
                method:"put",
                headers:{
                Accept:"application/json",
                "Content-Type":"application/json",
            },
                body:JSON.stringify({
                    postId:id
                })
            }).then(res=>res.json())
            .then(result=>{
                //console.log(result)
                const newData = data.map(post=>{
                    if(post._id===result._id){
                        return result
                    }else{
                        return post
                    }
                })
                setdata(newData)
            }).catch(err=>{
                console.log(err)
            })
        }
```

frontend code:

```
{posts.likes.includes(state._id)
                   ?<AiTwotoneDislike size="2em" onClick={()=>{unlikePost(posts._id)}}/>
                   :<AiFillLike size="2em" onClick={()=>{likePost(posts._id)}}/>
                    }
```

The main problem is in this above code only, it takes state._id, but only shows like button after clicking also. I have checked state, it does contain _id.

Comment: Please share _minimal_ reproducible code.

Comment: @SinanYaman please check now

Comment: Isn't `posts` an array? `posts._id` will not exist in this case. You should map over it

Comment: @SinanYaman I already did data.map(posts=>{} and then wrote code under it.

Comment: No I mean you call `likePost(posts._id)`, where do you get the posts? Is it an array? If it is a single post, the naming of the variable could use a refactor.

Comment: @SinanYaman its not a single post there are many posts and post is an object. I get post through fetching it in data and data was array so I did data.map(posts=>{} and then wrote the above code in it....I'll give u the whole code above check it.

Comment: if `posts` is an array, `posts._id` doesn't exist?